# CustomEditor GUI button hides all public fields in inspector?

Tags: unity

I am new to Unity. I have a simple game object with one script attached to it and then another script to add a button which will call the function within the script attached to the game object. My problem is I want to have two editable fields `height` and `width` but if the custom editor is added to the game object then those public fields no longer display in the inspector window...Not sure why?

WorldGenerator.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WorldGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

public int height;
public int width;

public void RunWorldGeneration()
{
    Generate worldGenerator = new Generate();
    float[,] world = worldGenerator.GenerateWorld(width, height);

}
}
```

WorldGeneratorEditor.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(WorldGenerator))] // If I comment this out the public variablbes show
// If it is uncommented, then just the button with "Generate" text shows
public class MapGeneratorEditor : Editor
{

public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    WorldGenerator worldGen = (WorldGenerator)target;

    if (GUILayout.Button("Generate"))
    {
        worldGen.RunWorldGeneration();
    };
}
}
```

[image: When the custom editor is active]

[image: When custom editor is inactive]

Comment: There are no errors, by the way. At least none in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs on [Editor.DrawDefaultInspector()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.DrawDefaultInspector.html):

> Description
>
> Draw the built-in inspector.
>
> Call this function from inside OnInspectorGUI method to draw the
>   automatic inspector. It is useful you don't want to redo the entire
>   inspector, but you want to add a few buttons to it.

If you don't include a call to this method, Unity will assume your custom inspector is drawing everything it wants drawn — that way you can draw fields in customised ways without them showing up twice, or hide serialised fields you don't want to edit directly.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best practise to add `base.OnInspectorGUI();` at the top of the `OnInspectorGUI()` method.

````
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    base.OnInspectorGUI();

    WorldGenerator worldGen = (WorldGenerator)target;

    if (GUILayout.Button("Generate"))
        worldGen.RunWorldGeneration();
}
```
````